# Cakephp2 on linux does not work with Sql Server (mssql)

Tags: sql-server, linux, cakephp, ubuntu, debian

I am having a hard time installing drivers for ODB Mssql. I need it to let my php communicate with an Sql server (2005).

The driver:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28160

Does someone know a alternative solution? Or an working example?
Please notice I am using cakePhp version 2+. Not 1.3.. Lots of documentation about this problem has been written for 1.3.

The driver for Mssql from MS is buggy. It needs a lot of libraries and still doesnt survive it's own installer..

My configuration is Ubuntu 12+ (with gui), Lampp (xampp for linux).

Answer (score 0):

Besides that you have issues installing the driver, CakePHP2 has no datasource for PDO and ODBC.

You can use this datasource to connect to SQL 2005 from CakePHP 2 without PDO and the driver.
This is a ported version of the 1.3 source: https://github.com/rchavik/datasources/tree/mssql-2.0

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but check its useful for you:

http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Configuring-MSSQL-Server-to-talk-to-PHP-in-Ubuntu-1810.php